# Disable TLS1.0 and TLS1.1 in keycloak(wildfly)

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

I am trying to disable TLS1.0 and TLS1.1 and mandating TLS1.2 on keycloak (client side only)

I am trying to do it through jvm > **bin/standalone.conf**:
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS ‑Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2"

The above implementation suites my requirement where only the client will have effect (e.g. LDAPS client etc) hence, -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 is ruled out.

However, while doing so, receive class not found:

```
JAVA_OPTS: -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true ‑Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2

=========================================================================

Error: Could not find or load main class ‑Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

Environment: Keycloak 6.0.1, Java 8, OpenJDK 1.8 / 1.11, OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018

Comment: What version of OpenSSL does your environment have?

Comment: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018

Comment: I may be wrong but shouldn't you diable TLS at web server level?

Comment: Well, as i mentioned in my query, want to disable for client only. For server configuration I understand that could be done by adding standalone.xml <https-listener> enabled-protocol attribute. But requirement is not to do it in server config.

Comment: My bad ... there were special characters (introduced to copy and paste). Manually typing resolved it.

Comment: Alright! I had similar copy error too when I tried it sometime back. Glad you resolved it.